# DNS (named) zone file loads correctly but does not resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, fedora, bind, dns-zone

I have a very strange problem that I not able to figure out.
On my server I host two applications with two different domains:
1. onlinelogistics.eu
2. resursecrestine.org

I also host a DNS server (fedora server) that I configured to resolve these two domains.
The problem is that only the first domain resolve and the other does not.

The zone file for 'onlinelogistics.eu' is:

```
onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      SOA     ns1.onlinelogistics.eu. root.onlinelogistics.eu. (

                        1194130303

                        10800

                        3600

                        604800

                        38400 )

@       IN      NS      onlinelogistics.eu.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      NS      ns1.onlinelogistics.eu.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      NS      ns2.onlinelogistics.eu.

ns1.onlinelogistics.eu. IN      A       85.25.124.83

ns2.onlinelogistics.eu. IN      A       85.25.124.83

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      A       85.25.124.83

www.onlinelogistics.eu. IN      A       85.25.124.83

ftp.onlinelogistics.eu. IN      A       85.25.124.83

m.onlinelogistics.eu.   IN      A       85.25.124.83

*.onlinelogistics.eu.   IN      A       85.25.124.83

                        IN      A       85.25.124.83

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      30 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      30 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      MX      30 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

onlinelogistics.eu.     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx a:onlinelogistics.eu ip4:85.25.124.83 ?all"onlinelogistics:~
```

Now, for the other domain I did a copy/paste and replaced onlinelogistics.eu with "resursecrestine.org" but still the domain is not found.

The comand "whois resursecrestine.org" finds the nameservers (ns1.resursecrestine.org) so I am sure the problem is with the DNS server not being able to find the address.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to replace your original IP addresses and names with placeholders...

Comment: Very bad advice for PEra: quite the contrary, use REAL names if you want people to help.

Comment: You did not mention the name server software you use. BIND ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you created the zone in your named.conf file? i.e.:

```
zone "resursecrestine.org" {
        type master;
        file "resursecrestine.org";
};
```

According to a dig +trace, it does resolve...and checking via browser, it loads. So is this resolved?

```
; <<>> DiG 9.2.4 <<>> +trace resursecrestine.org
;; global options:  printcmd
.                       306040  IN      NS      A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       306040  IN      NS      M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
;; Received 316 bytes from 172.18.251.240#53(172.18.251.240) in 1 ms

org.                    172800  IN      NS      B0.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.org.
org.                    172800  IN      NS      B2.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.org.
org.                    172800  IN      NS      A0.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.INFO.
org.                    172800  IN      NS      D0.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.org.
org.                    172800  IN      NS      C0.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.INFO.
org.                    172800  IN      NS      A2.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.INFO.
;; Received 439 bytes from 198.41.0.4#53(A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET) in 61 ms

resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns4.afraid.org.
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns3.afraid.org.
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns1.afraid.org.
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns2.afraid.org.
;; Received 180 bytes from 199.19.54.1#53(B0.ORG.AFILIAS-NST.org) in 42 ms

resursecrestine.org.    3600    IN      A       85.25.124.83
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns1.afraid.org.
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns4.afraid.org.
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns3.afraid.org.
resursecrestine.org.    86400   IN      NS      ns2.afraid.org.
;; Received 196 bytes from 208.43.71.243#53(ns4.afraid.org) in 29 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unlike what you say, `resursecrestine.org` works, it is `onlinelogistics.eu` which fails:

```
% check_soa onlinelogistics.eu
There was no response from ns2.onlinelogistics.eu
There was no response from ns1.onlinelogistics.eu
% check_soa resursecrestine.org
ns4.afraid.org has serial number 1001120004
ns1.afraid.org has serial number 1001120004
ns2.afraid.org has serial number 1001120004
ns3.afraid.org has serial number 1001120004
```

First thing to do, with every daemon running on Unix: **check the log file**! BIND, for instance, gives comprehensive information about the zones it loaded or failed to load. This would address greeblesnort's suggestion.

Also, "does not resolve" is not sufficiently precise. Test with `dig @your-name-server` and report the actual result.

Finally, your zone files would be simpler to read and easier to manage with [relative names](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/identical-domains-with-bind.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the ip address for the nameservers correct?  checkdns.net reports the nameservers (85.25.124.83) aren't responding.  If this ip address is correct, then likely Bind failed to start because you have errors in your zonefile or named.conf.local.  Check both of these using named-checkconf and named-checkzone.

Comment: And, above all, read BIND log file!